# Is there a way to use a For loop to add to a String? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, for-loop

I'm trying to add numbers onto a string. I want to loop through 1 To 80 for 'a' and 1 to 40 for 's' so that those numbers are added to strings r(1) and r(2).

The result I'm trying to get is formatted like this r(1) = "PD 1" and so on; r(2) = "QR 1" and so on.

```
Dim a As Integer

Dim s As Integer

Dim r(1 To 2) As String

For a = 1 To 100

    r(1) = ""PD " & "a""

Next a

For s = 1 To 40

    r(2) = "QR " & s

Next s
```

Comment: Do you want a large string with all the combinations concatenated together or do you want each combo as a different index in your array? currently you will just overwrite all but the last iteration.

Comment: Warcupine - I want them as a different index in my array. Later in the code, I have a For statement loop through r(1) and r(2).

Comment: So you want an array of arrays?

Comment: BigBen - yeah, I'm pretty sure that's what I'm looking for. I'm a novice at a lot of this, but I've managed to put some things together thanks to Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of arrays, perhaps:

```
Dim pd(1 To 100) As String
Dim qr(1 To 40) As String

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(pd) To UBound(pd)
    pd(i) = "PD " & i
Next

For i = LBound(qr) To UBound(qr)
    qr(i) = "QR " & i
Next

Dim r(1 To 2)
r(1) = pd
r(2) = qr
```

Comment: This is closer, but it just keeps going.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "just keeps going"? This is an array of arrays... `r(1)` contains the first array, and `r(2)` contains the second. The first inner array has 100 elements, and the second has 40.

Comment: It looks like it's repeating. Here's what it's returning:

PD 1, PD 1, PD 2, PD 2

etc.

Comment: How are you determining what it's "returning"?

Comment: I have it printing out to a Word document. The code looks at the values in a column of cells. If the value "PD 1" (etc.) matches what's in the column, it returns information for that whole row.

Comment: What *code* are you using to determine what it's returning?

Comment: What works is when I enumerate what r equals like this:

r(1) = "PD 1", r(2) = "PD 2" (etc.)

Comment: But you can't do that with an array of arrays... you have to do `r(1)(1)`. I honestly don't see the benefits of using an array here at all to be honest, much less an array of arrays, given the code you've provided.

Comment: BigBen - I appreciate that. I wasn't sure of the limitations here, so I appreciate the information.

Comment: I mean it's not a limitation... I guess, maybe if you add more code to your original question to explain what your end goal is, maybe that'll lead to a better solution.